# Is there a closed form for the recurrence with $N(r,1)=N(r,r)=1$ and $N(r,c)=cN(r-1,c)+N(r-1,c-1)$ for $1<c<r$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find if there is a closed form solution to the recurrence relation (where $1 \leq c \leq r$):

$$
N(r,c) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} 1, & \text{if} & c=1,r, \\ c N(r-1,c) + N(r-1,c-1), & \text{if} & 1 < c < r,  \end{array} \right. 
$$

This is like a deformed Pascal's triangle if you interpret $c$ as column and $r$ as row.

Comment: looks like Stirling numbers

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh it’s looks like you’re right. Any idea how I might make the connection to Stirling numbers?

Comment: If a given sequence matches the base and recurrence relations, then it must be a closed form of that recurrence.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Okay. I’m trying to see if there are techniques that one could use to find the closed form solution without knowing it ahead of time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation -- sorry, you have the same recurrence relation but different initial values.

Comment: There are no general techniques to find closed form solutions except in special cases. What you can do is calculate a few terms of the sequence and then try looking for it in [OEIS](https://oeis.org).